# How can I downgrade KDE5 to KDE4 but keep the login manager?

Tags: kde, plasma-5

Title says it all...I want my plasma 4 desktop back but I am absolutely in love with the new lock screen, even over GDM and such. Any way to do this, or any way to uninstall it all then reinstall that login manager?